# Стек exception'ов, как обработать все?

Tags: c++, исключения

Вопрос на засыпку, кто знает, можно ли перехватить MyException1 в func3?

```
#include <iostream>

class MyException1: public std::exception {
public:
    virtual const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return "Error1";
    }
};

class MyException21: public std::exception {
public:
    virtual const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return "Error21";
    }
};

class MyException22: public std::exception {
public:
    virtual const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return "Error22";
    }
};

void func1(){
    throw MyException1();
}

void func2(){
    throw MyException1();
}

void func12(){
    try {
        func1();
    }catch (MyException1& exception1){
        throw MyException21();
    }
}

void func22(){
    try {
        func2();
    }catch (MyException1& exception1){
        throw MyException22();
    }
}

void func3(){
    try {
        func12();
        func22();
    }catch (MyException1& exception1){
        std::cout<<exception1.what(); // Вот здесь должно выводиться "Error1"
    }catch (MyException21& exception21){
        std::cout<<exception21.what(); // Но выводится "Error21", что логично, но как вот весь стек ошибок перехватить, т.е. MyException1 тоже?
    }
}

int main() {
    func3();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нет смысла в том, что ваши классы наследуют  std::exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас нет никакого стека исключений. Функция `func12();` ловит `MyException1` и кидает **вместо него** `MyException21`.

Answer (score 0):

> можно ли перехватить MyException1 в func3?

Нет. Клади его (или информацию из него) внутрь `MyException21`, если надо.